# How to handover multilevel hashtable in perl

Tags: perl, hashtable

I'm totally stuck to a problem:

I do have some huge perl scripts with several huge multilevel hash_tables.
Everything works fine, but for reducing code and readability, i would like to hand over the last hash reference to a subfunction.

As mentioned before, I do have several different hash tables, e.g.
%hash_table1 and %hash_table2, both have the same values, but different levels for the keys.

hash_table1 with 3 level of keys:

```
$hash_table1{$key1}{$key2}{$key3}->{value1}
$hash_table1{$key1}{$key2}{$key3}->{value2}
$hash_table1{$key1}{$key2}{$key3}->{value3}
```

I do have the same "values" in an other hash_table, but with a different multilevel:
hash_table2 with 2 level of keys:

```
$hash_table2{$key1}{$key2}->{value1}
$hash_table2{$key1}{$key2}->{value2}
$hash_table2{$key1}{$key2}->{value3}
```

I can easily access all the values separately by just copy past all the code, change amount of keys in it, but most of the time, i do have like 20 different values so ... amount of code to access the data is ... well ... huge. Additionally, if something needs to be changed, i would have to change it multiple times ;(

what i would like to have is something like the following sub function where i basically just store the last hash key reference in a temporary hash table to easily access all the values of different hash tables in the same way (this is the part which is not working!!!):

```
sub print_all_values {
    my %hash_tmp = shift @_;
    printf $hash_tmp->{value1}.";";
    printf $hash_tmp->{value2}.";";
    printf $hash_tmp->{value3}."\n";
}
```

and somewhere in the code i handle through the multilevels and just pass the last reference to the previous defined sub function to do ... well what ever should be done there with the stored values (lets say just printing):

```
foreach my $k1 (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %hash_table1){
   foreach my $k2 (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %{$hash_table1{$k1}}){
      foreach my $k3 (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %{$hash_table1{$k1}{$k2}}
         print_all_values(%{$hash_table1{$k1}{$k2}{$k3}});
      }
   }
}
```

end somewhere else the code to access the two level hash_table:

```
foreach my $k1 (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %hash_table2){
   foreach my $k2 (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %{$hash_table2{$k1}}){
      print_all_values(%{$hash_table2{$k1}{$k2}});
   }
}
```

As mentioned before, it would just be nice to have a working solution to pass over the last hash reference to a sub function for basically access all the stored values at once.

Many thanks in advance for any helpful comment,

all the best,

OldMcFunsy

Comment: Ow! This makes my brain hurt. This solution is crying out for an [Object Oriented approach](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html). It will help keep all of your hash keys in sync. Give me a bit more info about what the various keys represent, and I might be able to work up a quick answer. Object Oriented will help you handle this mess of keys and hash levels and keep your code much cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: `%hash_tmp` and `$hash_tmp->{key}` are not referring to the same hash!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References)

You ought to just pass a reference to a sub:

```
print_all_values(\%hash_table);

sub print_all_values {
    my $hash_tmp = shift;
    printf $hash_tmp->{value1}.";";
    printf $hash_tmp->{value2}.";";
    printf $hash_tmp->{value3}."\n";
}
```

Comment: many thanks, i would never have though about declaring my hash_tmp as reference and not as hash_table. just changed from % to $. You can not imagine how many hours i spent with trying this code to work. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
sub print_all_values {
    print(join(";", @_), "\n");
}

for my $k1 (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %hash_table1) {
   for my $k2 (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %{ $hash_table1{$k1} }) {
      print_all_values(
         @{ $hash_table1{$k1}{$k2} }{
            sort {$a <=> $b} keys %{ $hash_table1{$k1}{$k2} }
         }
      );
   }
}
```

Sorry, no time for explanations.

Comment: Hi, thanks both of you, both solutions work and fullfill my requirements.
You can not imagine how many hours i spent to solve the problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
sub print_all_values {
    my %hash_tmp = shift @_;
    printf $hash_tmp->{value1}.";";
    printf $hash_tmp->{value2}.";";
    printf $hash_tmp->{value3}."\n";
}
```

`$hash_tmp->{value1}` is referencing something totally separate from `%hash_tmp`. Changing these to `$hash_tmp{value1}` will probably fix the issue. Also, always use strict and warnings.

Answer (score 0):

This should work but I don't have any complicated hashes to test it on. :)

```
# --------------------------------------
#       Name: scan_hash
#      Usage: %value_of = scan_hash( \%hash_tree, @keys );
#    Purpose: To do a depth first scan of the hash tree
#             and create a hash of the leaves.
# Parameters: \%hash_tree -- Tree to scan
#                   @keys -- List of keys; these may appear anywhere in the tree
#    Returns:   %value_of -- a simple key=>value has,
#                            the keys are from @keys
#                            and their values are what was found
#
sub scan_hash {
  my $hash_tree = shift @_;
  my @keys      = @_;
  my %value_of  = ();

  for my $key ( keys %$hash_tree ){

    # save if the current key is one we're looking for
    if( grep { $_ eq $key } @keys ){
      $value_of{$key} = $hash_tree->{$key};

    # is it a reference?
    }elsif( my $ref = ref( $hash_tree->{$key} )){

      if( $ref eq 'HASH' ){

        # hash references are scanned via recursion
        my %new_value_of = scan_hash( $hash_tree->{$key}, @keys );

        # stored using slices: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices
        @value_of{ keys %new_value_of } = values %new_value_of;

      }else{
        die "cannot handle a $ref reference\n";
      }

    } # end if

  } # end for

  return %value_of;
}
```